# How is the correct form to write a "if" conditional?

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, spanish

I want to know what is my mistake in this Bash scripting. It enters the `for` loop but when entering the `if` condition it only chooses the `else` option. The exercise is to count the even and the odd and I am using the **Termux** application:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
echo "Ingrese un numero"
read n
impar=0
par=0
for ((i=1; i<=$n ; i++));
do
 if [[$(($i%2)) -eq  0]];
 then
  ((par++))
 else
  ((impar++))
 fi
done
echo "Pares: $par"
echo "Impares: $impar"
```

I try to investigate but the information about `if` is different from one another. Please help me with that.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Relevant code and error messages need to be included in your question *as text*, [not as pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/328193).  Just linking to screen shots makes it more difficult for people to help you.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Copy your script and paste it into https://www.shellcheck.net/ - It usually provides a lot of helpful hints

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the input you use, the actual output and the expected output. To check for errors in your script, paste it at https://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need space after `[[` but you could also use arithmetic expansion in the `if` statement too. Note that you don't need `$` before your variables in arithmetic expansion:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

read -rp "Ingrese un numero: " n

for (( i=1; i<=n; i++ )); do
    if (( i % 2 )); then
        ((impar++))
    else
        ((par++))
    fi
done

echo "Pares: $par"
echo "Impares: $impar"
```

A simpler version of your script could calculate the result without loops. You know there's at least the same amount of `impar`s as there are `par`s - and there are `n / 2` `pars` (with integer truncation). If you've given an uneven number as input, `impar` is equal to `par + 1` or simply `impar = n - par`.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

read -rp "Ingrese un numero: " n

(( par = n / 2 ))
(( impar = n - par ))

echo "Pares: $par"
echo "Impares: $impar"
```

Comment: Sorry but, you can give me a example for a good write "if" conditional?

Comment: @Javi `if [[ "$variable" -eq "$value" ]]` could be one for numerical comparisons. The spaces are important.

Answer (score 2):

The script you've provided has a few issues that need to be corrected to make it work properly. Here's my version of the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Ingrese un numero"
read n
impar=0
par=0
for (( i=1; i<=$n; i++ ));
do
  if [ $((i % 2)) -eq 0 ];
  then
    ((par++))
  else
    ((impar++))
  fi
done
echo "Pares: $par"
echo "Impares: $impar"
```

**Here's what I fixed:**

Inside the `if` statement, you should have a space after [ and before ], and also a space around the `$((i % 2))` expression. So it should be `[ $((i % 2)) -eq 0 ]` instead of `[[$(($i%2)) -eq 0]]`.

With these changes, the script should correctly count and display the number of even (pares) and odd (impares) numbers between 1 and the input number n.

Comment: `if [ $((i % 2)) -eq 0 ]; then ((par++)); else ((impar++)); fi` = `if (( i % 2 )); then ((impar++)); else ((par++)); fi`, no need for the extra test with `-eq 0`.